# How to overrides the OpenJDK details?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I am using `Linux` box and setup the `Oracle 12c` instance and `Java JDK`. **This question has nothing to do with the classNotFound error**

```
[user@10.XXX-XX-00:~]$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
[user@10.XXX-XX-00:~]$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_144
[user@10.XXX-XX-00:~]$
```

also in **.profile** file. I setup the following paths:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0_144 #/usr/java
export ANT_HOME=/sys_apps_01/apache-ant-1.9.4
export M2_HOME=/sys_apps_01/apache-maven-2.2.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
export ORACLE_HOME=/vol_01/oracle/product/v11.2.0.3/
export PATH=$M2:$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
```

but when I used `java -version` and `javac -version`, then why I am getting the OpenJDK details?

when I find for openJDK. I did not get anything.

```
[root@10.XXX-XX-00 ~]# find / -name "openjdk"
[root@10.XXX-XX-00 ~]#
```

For user it seems environment variables has been set and not for the root user. How to solve this error?

Application giving me following error -

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.crypto.JceSecurity
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:653)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:596)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.batch.mapper.RawRecordFieldSetMapper.decriptValue(RawRecordFieldSetMapper.java:126)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.batch.mapper.RawRecordFieldSetMapper.mapFieldSet(RawRecordFieldSetMapper.java:87)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.batch.mapper.RawRecordLineMapper.mapLine(RawRecordLineMapper.java:19)
    at com.mastercard.ess.eds.batch.mapper.RawRecordLineMapper.mapLine(RawRecordLineMapper.java:12)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader.doRead(FlatFileItemReader.java:180)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.read(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy45.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.SynchronizedItemStreamReader.read(SynchronizedItemStreamReader.java:55)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:91)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:87)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:144)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:110)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:69)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:406)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:330)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:271)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:81)
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Details**

> uname -a
>
> Linux ech-10-XXX-XX-00 2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 17:03:21 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I found the

```
/usr/lib/jvm
[user@:/usr/lib/jvm]$ ll
total 4.0K
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K May 21 23:01 java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9.x86_64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 Jun 20 07:57 jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   51 Jun 20 07:57 jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64 -> java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el6_9.x86_64/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   21 Jun 20 07:57 jre -> /etc/alternatives/jre
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   29 Jun 20 07:57 jre-openjdk -> /etc/alternatives/jre_openjdk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   27 Jun 20 07:57 jre-1.8.0 -> /etc/alternatives/jre_1.8.0
[user@:/usr/lib/jvm]$
```

Any guidance now ?

Comment: Did not specified which Linux distribution you using, but see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/740757/switch-between-multiple-java-versions

Comment: uname -a 
Linux ech-10-XXX-XX-00 2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 5 17:03:21 PDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: [Never post pictures of text when you can post the actual text. Be sure that it is properly formatted and readable.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Ok I got it. Corrected. Please remove downvote. It blocks us to ask the questions

Answer (score 0):

Just because you have set `JAVA_HOME`, does not mean that running `java` and `javac` will pick up the commands from this directory.

The search path for executibles is actually stored in the `PATH` variable.

Try this:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This will prepend your defined Java home to the beginning of the path, meaning that when searching for `java`, this will be the first location checked.

To find the binary that you are _actually running, use

```
which java
>/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java
```